# conect to server via node net client

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to connect to some server using a net node. The client needs authorization (username only). I send the username to the server, but the server returns to me what I sent. Sorry, I'm a new user of node and network. I tried via TELNET and evrythink works fine. Thanks!!

```
let net = require('net');
const HOST = '192.168.0.2';
const PORT = 23;
let client=null;
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

function write_data(client){
  readline.question(client.on('data',(data)=>{console.log(data.toString());}), (username) => {
    client.write(`${username}`);
    readline.close();
  });
}

client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST , ()=>{});
setTimeout(function() {write_data(client)},0);//-------> to server "as"
```

[with node js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvRaN.png)
[Telnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COdZU.png)